# Multiply integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: integer

I'm trying to multiply `integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is 2147483647) by 2. When I execute the program, it shows that `integer.MAX_VALUE` is -2.

Why is it -2?

Answer (score 6):

Many modern computer architectures represent integers in binary as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Adding 2147483647 to itself causes an overflow resulting in a -2 representation.

```
 011111111111111111111111
+011111111111111111111111
-------------------------
 111111111111111111111110
```

From the above you can see that the sign bit (first one) is now 1, signifying a negative number, and that all other bits apart from the last are 1, together meaning a -2 in two's complement.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit integer which is signed.
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 
*2
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110

the first bit represents the sign. an overflow will cause the sign to change.

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 is -2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Another experiment I recommend is to try it with an unsigned int (uint).